# (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null") when submitting form - Django

Tags: django, forms

When I try and upload an image, I am getting an error (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null") however, there is no user_id column. I tried setting user = models.OneToOneField(null=False), but it did not work.

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=140, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    website = models.URLField(default='')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', default='profile_image/Default.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateBioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            'image',
            'city',
            'website',
            'description',
        )
        widgets = {
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 4, 'cols': 15}),
        }

    def save(self, commit=True):
        savedBio = super(UpdateBioForm, self).save(commit=False)
        savedBio.image = self.cleaned_data['image']
        savedBio.city = self.cleaned_data['city']
        savedBio.website = self.cleaned_data['website']
        savedBio.description = self.cleaned_data['description']


        if commit:
            savedBio.save()

        return savedBio
```

views.py

```
def update_bio(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateBioForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = UpdateBioForm(instance=request.user)
    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/update_bio.html', context=args)
```

Comment: You'd need null=True, surely? But there's a whole lot of things wrong with this code otherwise, starting from the fact that the instance needs to be a profile, not a user.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the non-`POST` case to pass in a `UserProfile` instead of a `User` object, maybe as follows:

```
else:
    profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    form = UpdateBioForm(instance=profile)
```

Also, I don't think you need to re-write all that `save` logic, that will come by nature of using `ModelForm`.